# Saving cell properties for handsontable

Tags: save, metadata, handsontable, saving-data

[In handsontable documentation](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.1/tutorial-load-and-save.html), it is suggested that we used the `hot.getData()` method to get the data of the current instance, and then be able to save that data to the database (where `hot` is an instance of handsontable). the `hot.gatData()` method returns an array of arrays, of all the data in the handsontable.

the problem is, each cell has other properties/metadata that I like to save (most importantly, the `type` property). That metadata is not returned as part of the `hot.getData()` method. So if I want to retrieve my saved data and use the that table correctly in future, I need a way of saving the cell properties.

How can I do that? I could not find that in documentation.

Thank.s